# Multiple running application instances

Tags: applications, task-management, processes

I'm an owner of Android 4.2.2 device.

For a while, I can see identical apps in `Settings->Apps->Running`:

- "Baidu IME" x 2
- "Google Services" x 2
- "GO Weather EX" x 3
- "GO Launcher Z" x 2
- "GO SMS Pro" x 2

Would they all have just two instances I would think that this is caused by two google accounts registered in the system, but why then I have three running "GO Weather EX"?

Comment: If you tap them, you would see entries showing what  category they belong to, a process or a service. You may try [OS Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in Android,The processes may look the same. But it may do different functions.Inn Your case, GO Weather EX kill the two instance & check if that app works properly and comeback to Settings->Apps->Running page. If again 3 instances are running then Each of them may do different functions